# How can I denominate levels of lists in R?

Tags: r, list

I would like to denominate the levels of a list, as with `rownames()` or `colnames()` when denominating rows and columns of matrices.

Example:

```
a<-matrix(rep(1,4),2,2)
b<-matrix(rep(2,9),3,3)
list<-list(a,b)
print(list)
```

Instead of returning `[[1]]` at the first level I want the list to use some string like 'matrix a' instead. Maybe this is simple to do.

Comment: +1 for to-the-point question and reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `names`:

```
names(list) = c("A","B")

> list
$A
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1

$B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    2    2
[2,]    2    2    2
[3,]    2    2    2

list[["A"]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1
```

Note that in general it is not good practice to use R reserved words such as `list` as variable names.

Comment: As with a lot of things in life :)